# Understanding the difference between django-admin runserver and mange.py runserver

Tags: django, django-admin

What is the basic difference between the django.admin and manage.py?

Also,  What is the meaning of the sentence, "manage.py acts as a "thin wrapper
around django.py" ?

Comment: If one works and one doesn't, why would you want to use the one that doesn't?

Comment: I wanted to know the reason.

Comment: Hey Akansha - so based on the documentation, manage.py is a thin wrapper around django-admin.py. I've never worked with wrappers before but based on my understanding with them, programmers tend to write wrappers for 'legacy software' [and some other use cases i'm not familiar with]. These wrappers enable programmers to use a 'legacy library' that otherwise couldn't be used. I guess the question you should ask is what the difference between manage.py and django-admin.py. Why one should use the other, I don't think I read that in the documentation actually. Hope that sheds some light.

Comment: @AkankshaSingh, have you tried looking at django-admin.py and manage.py, to be honest, a thin wrapper to me is a buzz word. Looking at the source code, all manage.py is doing is setting up the app.settings to your environment then using using the method from django.core.management to execute whatever command you've typed. So that's basically the difference based on the source code in manage.py. Have you figure out the difference?

Comment: Can someone in the django-community give a reason why we need a manage.py. Why can't django-admin.py set up the settings for us? Why do we need a manage.py/why does django generate manage.py?

Comment: @macmania314 I am stuck up at the word "thin wrapper", I am not able to understand it's contextual meaning.

Comment: what do you not understand? have you checked out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_library? Might also want to check out this design pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern which is something that wrappers are based upon.

Comment: So, I'm answering my question on "why can't django admin setup the settings for us". I believe it's because every settings app name will be different, so you have to have a unique instantiation of 'django-admin' but since there's already a django-admin.py, it makes more sense to make another .py file that extends from django-admin.py. If any core contributors of django could comment if this logic makes sense, that would make my day. @AkankshaSingh, I hope that sheds some light on your question about thin wrappers, to be honest, don't think about thin wrapper and just look at the source code.

Comment: The source code tells all :)

Answer (score 2):

here is the documentation doc that outlines the difference between django-admin and manage.py:

django-admin.py is Django’s command-line utility for administrative tasks. This document outlines all it can do.

> In addition, manage.py is automatically created in each Django
>   project. manage.py is a thin wrapper around django-admin.py that takes
>   care of two things for you before delegating to django-admin.py:
>
> - It puts your project’s package on sys.path.
> - It sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable so that it points to your project’s settings.py file.

Here's more documentation explaining the difference: 
https://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.4/ref/django-admin.html
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/

To add what I said on the comments above - manage.py is needed because every app name will be different and you have to specify your app's settings to run your django app successfully. There's really no difference between django-admin and manage.py except this one line

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "[App name].settings")
```

everything that you type after manage.py, django-admin.py takes care of as shown:

```
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Sometimes, it helps just looking at the source code to see what is really going on if the documentation doesn't help.